# How to do a serial port loopback in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, serial-port

I'm new to Ubuntu, I have a PC running on Ubuntu 18.04, it has `02 RS232` serial port.

How can I do a loopback test on the serial port?

I had tried `dmesg | grep tty` , It returns :

```
[ 0.141242] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[ 1.593150] printk: console [ttyS2] enabled
[ 6.095807] serial8250: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[ 6.125392] serial8250: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

I had tried `cat /dev/ttyS2` in one terminal.

Then I tried `echo "hi" > /dev/ttyS2` in another terminal.

But it doesn't seems to be working.

I had tried `putty`.

Then I tried `echo "hi" > /dev/ttyS2` in one terminal.

But there is no reply in `putty` too.

Is there any thing that I had missed out?

Please kindly advice.

Thank you!